# Bootstrap wysiwyg textarea editor working on Bootstrap 3

Tags: android, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a wysiwyg textarea editor for Bootstrap 3. Everything I can find on Google only works with Bootstrap 2. Has anybody an good, simple wysiwyg Edtor for Bootstrap 3?

Comment: why is there android tag here !?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks for the Tip of wysihtml5. I found a solution for Bootstrap 2 and wysihtml5: [bootstrap-wysihtml5](http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/). I update it to Bootstrap 3: [bootstrap3-wysihtml5](http://schnawel007.github.io/bootstrap3-wysihtml5/).

Comment: Not great features as summernote.

Answer (score 45):

[Awesome Summernote](http://summernote.org)

Super Simple WYSIWYG Editor on Bootstrap 3

```
<textarea name="summernote" id="summernote" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Call Summernote

```
$('#summernote').summernote({height: 300});
```

### [**DEMO jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/2AeHs/show/)

[image: Super Simple WYSIWYG Editor on Bootstrap 3]

Comment: This is the best one i ever found for bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [wysihtml5](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5) in one of my Bootstrap 3 projects and is working fine; perhaps only tweaked a few icons to make it look nice.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record. I added a fork of bootstrap-wysihtml5 to bower:

https://github.com/Waxolunist/bootstrap3-wysihtml5-bower

```
bower install bootstrap3-wysihtml5-bower
```

The old one seems not to be maintained. This one is. Pull requests welcome.

Comment: The original repo seems available through bower by now: `bower install bootstrap-wysihtml5`

Comment: Seems someone added the link to bower. But the repo does not contain a bower.json. The repo is still unmaintained.

Answer (score 0):

To help the edit of HTML code under Bootstrap3 or Foundation framework, I have been developing
a kind of intuitive but not wysiwyg app, not useful for design the CSS outlook, but can be used
to easily change the layout: http://www.mkrrf-it.com/cloedit/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend

http://www.web-forge.info/projects/materialNote

it has redo and undo ability and href , tables and media controlled smoothly plus there is fonts

[image: how cool is that]